# Running multiple web services on one website

Tags: server, php, services

I want to run two different services at two different ports at a Ubuntu VPS. For this purpose I created two different service files /etc/systemd/system/myfirst-server.service and /etc/systemd/system/mysecond-server.service

These files are

```
[Unit]
  Description=Chat Server

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path1/bin/myfirst-server.php
  StandardOutput=null
  Restart=always
  RestartSec=10

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```
[Unit]
  Description=Chat Server

  [Service]
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path2/bin/mysecond-server.php
  StandardOutput=null
  Restart=always
  RestartSec=10

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I am running them by

```
sudo systemctl enable myfirst-server.service
sudo systemctl enable mysecond-server.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start myfirst-server.service
sudo systemctl start mysecond-server.service
```

Now the issue is if I run one of them it work perfectly well but with two of the they start behaving unpredictably- at one time they run good at other time one does not run. Strangely enough both of them respond to WSS connecting perfectly well.

Any help about how to run two services

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path1/bin/myfirst-server.php
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/path2/bin/mysecond-server.php
```

simultaneously is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that this is the way to do it :) The issue was somewhere else, it was actually MySQL taking timeout after 8 hours of inactivity. So put a cron jobs like
0 0,8.16 * * * systemctl restart myfirst-server.service and its working well for now.